# Why does my pdo statement result always return true?

Tags: php, pdo

I am converting an old login script from mysql_query into pdo and I am struggling somewhat

All I am trying to do is find out of an email exist in the database or not!

My Code

```
public function doesEmailExist($userEmail)
{

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=servershop', 'user', 'pass');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`uid`) FROM `user` WHERE `email`= ?");
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $userEmail);

    try
    {

        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        if($rows == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Regardless of if the email exists in the table or not, the code is always returning true?

Is there not a simple way to do this like count_rows in sql?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($rows)` to see what you get?

Comment: Could you post the old, **working** MySQL code just for comparison with your new code?

Comment: @Niet string '0' (length=1)

Comment: Okay, now wherever you're calling this function, make it `var_dump($this->doesEmailExist($userEmail))` (or similar)

Comment: @Phil sorry, its gone :-) However it was your basic select * from table where conditionismet -> $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: @Niet string '1' (length=1)
null

Comment: Right, that's not right because your function is supposed to be returning `true` or `false`. Your function *cannot* return the string you are showing, it's not capable of doing that. Therefore, you aren't showing all your code and therefore it's impossible to diagnose ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$rows = (int) $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

And it should work.

Comment: `C:\Users\Niet>php -r "var_dump('0' == 1);"` prints `bool(false)` -- I refute your claim that "if you do '0' == 1 it will be true"

Comment: @Henrique, Regardless of the symatics, you actual answer works like a charm :-)

Comment: Yeah, and that's weird. I'll do some tests when I'm home to figure out why this works...